# Unable to turn on HP zd7000 Wireless on 12.04

Tags: wireless

I have installed 12.04 on a zd7000 everything is working except for the wireless.  The Broadcom STA drivers are installed and active.  Just cannot get the wireless to turn on.

Please advise.

Output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

```
02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: 02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Broadcom STA driver, also known as bcmwl-kernel-source, is incorrect for your device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

After it finishes, detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: Working!  There is no light on the on/off button, but that does not matter.  Thank you very for your time!

Comment: How do I do that?